# Migrate Excel Data to SQL

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssms, vba

I have a large table of information (around 11,000 rows, 4 columns) in Excel that uses a macro and I need to import it to an SQL server, Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, which will be utilized by another server to get the new information.

Example:
If I type into SQL:

```
Insert Into ENT_LINK_OBJECTS (OBJ_NAME, ENTITY_KEY, IDENTITY_KEY)
Select 'TDS-C1487-81236', ITEM_KEY, 1
From ENT_ITEM_MASTER As M
Where M.ITEM_CODE = 'TL-123'
or M.ITEM_CODE = 'TL-456'
```

I can then open the program which holds all this information, called Matrix, which prompts me to enter an item key and/or code and/or type etc (which has all possible files listed below it) and hit search (image 1). If I type in TL-123 to the item code section (image 2), it narrows down the files to any containing TL-123 (image 3). When i double click, I can click on many tabs, one of which is "Links". In that tab under document name the information TDS-C1487-81236(image 4). How would I go about making that happen?

(1)

[image]

(2)

[image]

Then hit **ENTER**

(3)

[image]

(4)

[image]

The website below is a good explanation of what I am getting at but I do not know how to implement it. What would be the most efficient way to migrate the data from my excel document to the SQL server?

http://sqlmag.com/business-intelligence/excel-macro-creates-insert-statements-easy-data-migration

Comment: Can you save the excel as tab-separated text file and use bcp to import it?

Comment: What if you use the Import Wizard in SSMS (right-click on the destination database node --> Tasks --> Import Wizard)?

Comment: @JamesZ I succesfully saved it as a tab-separated text file. Could you tell me what a bcp is and how I would import it with that? I am new to SQL and VBA

Comment: @lucazav I will try that out. What exactly is the destination database node? I'm looking around for it and cannot seem to locate it. I am new to SSMS

Comment: It's just the icon in SSMS of the database you want as destination of your data

Comment: Here you can find a tutorial: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/203/simple-way-to-import-data-into-sql-server/

Comment: @lucazav I am trying to import the file and it says it needs to be an excel file not an excel macro. If I run the macro. Is there a way to change this?

Comment: Is your file a XLSM file?

Comment: @lucazav yes, I have detailed more in the description above as I now realize it is a bit more complicated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a linked server or Use statement like OPENROWSET to access Excel Sheet. That would be the easiest and fastest method of accessing excel sheet via SQL.

Comment: can you give me an example of that or a link to a good example? I am new to SQL @AnandKumar

Comment: I have detailed my question more to give a better example of what I need

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried DTSWizard ? Its a GUI based tool to do so.. and should be shipped with MS SQL server

Comment: I haven't tried that but I'll look into it @kamokaze thank you! How exactly do I use that?

Comment: I have detailed my question more to give a better example of what I need @kamokaze